# Least involved proof for continuos functions $\Rightarrow$ uniform continuous functions on $[a,b]$

Tags: continuity, proof-writing, proof-explanation, uniform-continuity

I have been looking at this proof in my textbook and seem to always get lost in its logic, its roughly 3 pages long. The proof is:

---

*If f is continuous on a closed interval [a,b], then f is uniformly continuous on [a,b].*

---

Do any of you know of a nice, clean and quick proof for this? Asking my professor has only resulted in more confusion, and google helps little to none.

I greatly appreciate your help in advance!

Comment: Check Spivak's proof in his Calculus book.

Comment: @PedroTamaroff Perhaps you should have just linked him to your answer :-) http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/333125/a-continuous-function-f-from-a-closed-bounded-interval-a-b-into-mathbb/333129#333129

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/110573/continuous-function-on-a-compact-metric-space-is-uniformly-continuous

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose for contradiction that $f$ is continuous but not uniformly continuous on $[a,b]$. Then there exists $\varepsilon > 0$ such that for every $n \in \mathbb{N}$ there exist $x_n, y_n \in [a,b]$ with $|x_n - y_n| < \frac{1}{n}$ and $|f(x_n) - f(y_n)| \ge \varepsilon$. By the Bolzano-Weierstrass theorem, the sequence $(x_n)$ has a convergent subsequence $(x_{n_k})$; say $x_{n_k} \to x \in [a,b]$. Now you have 
$$
|y_{n_k} - x| \le |y_{n_k} - x_{n_k}| + |x_{n_k} - x| \le \frac{1}{n_k} + |x_{n_k} - x| \to 0
$$
and so $y_{n_k} \to x$ as well.

Since $f$ is continuous at $x$ and since $x_{n_k}, y_{n_k} \to x$, we have $f(x_{n_k}) \to f(x)$ and $f(y_{n_k}) \to f(x)$. In particular, there exists $k$ such that $|f({x_{n_k}}) - f(x)| < \varepsilon/2$ and $|f(y_{n_k}) - f(x)| < \varepsilon/2$. So the triangle inequality forces $|f(x_{n_k}) - f(y_{n_k})| < \varepsilon$, which contradicts the choice of the sequences $x_n$ and $y_n$.

Comment: Incidentally, I bet that something very close to this proof appears in most elementary real analysis texts. I'm pretty sure that this is the proof in "Real Analysis, an introductory course" by John Giles, for example.