# Uniform continuity of $A\log A$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, entropy, nuclear-norm

Let $A,B$ be finite dimensional full-rank positive semidefinite Hermitian matrices with unit trace. Let $|A-B|_1 \leq \varepsilon$ where $|X|_1 = \text{Tr}(\sqrt{X^*X})$ and $X^*$ is the transpose conjugate of $X$. $\varepsilon$ can be chosen arbitrarily small. If so, can one bound

$$|A\log A - B\log B|_1$$

in terms of $\varepsilon$?

Possible related question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2880806/99503) and also note the [Fannes inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fannes%E2%80%93Audenaert_inequality) for entropies does pretty much this for $|\text{Tr}(A\log A) - \text{Tr}(B\log B)|$.

Comment: It might be possible to adapt the [proof of the F-A inequality presented here](https://cs.uwaterloo.ca/~watrous/TQI/TQI.5.pdf) (page 272 of the text, 23rd page of the pdf) to get some kind of inequality